# upload file with same format using beego

Tags: file-upload, go, beego

File Uploading is done but not with the same name as filename 
i have tried this in html file

```html
<html>
 <title>Go upload</title>
 <body>

 <form action="http://localhost:8080/receive" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

and in beego/go receive.go

```html
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "io"
 "net/http"
 "os"
)

func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

 // the FormFile function takes in the POST input id file
 file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")

 if err != nil {
  fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
  return
 }

 defer file.Close()

 out, err := os.Create("/home/vijay/Desktop/uploadfile")
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "Unable to create the file for writing. Check your write access privilege")
  return
 }

 defer out.Close()

 // write the content from POST to the file
 _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
 }

 fmt.Fprintf(w, "File uploaded successfully : ")
 fmt.Fprintf(w, header.Filename)
}

func main() {
 http.HandleFunc("/", uploadHandler)
 http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

i am able to achieve uploading file here with same format... but not with the same name..
now i want this file to be uploaded with same name as file name

Comment: If the request isn't hitting the server, this code is being executed at all, so there's not much we can help with. Also not sure what beego has to do with this, since you're not importing or using beego for anything.

Comment: You're ignoring the error from `http.ListenAndServer`, are you certain that you're only running one server?

Comment: @JimB, yes only one server is running

Comment: You're naming the new file `uploadfile`. What doesn't work if you use the file name instead?

Comment: it will show no permission.. since its just directory without uploadFile

Answer (score 7):

You are not using a Beego controller to handle the upload

```
package controllers

import (
        "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

type MainController struct {
        beego.Controller
}

function (this *MainController) GetFiles() {
    this.TplNames = "aTemplateFile.html"

    file, header, er := this.GetFile("file") // where <<this>> is the controller and <<file>> the id of your form field
    if file != nil {
        // get the filename
        fileName := header.Filename
        // save to server
        err := this.SaveToFile("file", somePathOnServer)
    }
}
```